# First schematic - Critique my ATMEGA-328P design

Tags: arduino, atmega, atmel

I'm a software engineer looking to dabble in making electronics, and want to design my own board.  I thought that an Arduino would be a good place to start, so I created this with an ATMEGA-328P.

Could someone provide input on the accuracy and function of the design, and how I could improve?  Thanks in advance.

[image: Schematic (Image)]

Comment: See figure 24-9 of the ATmega328 datasheet on how to wire up AVcc correctly. You may also want to wire a noise reduction cap to ARef. Think of a debouncing circuit for the -RESET pin. Either another cap to GND, an R/S flip-flop and a SPDT button or a dedicated reset chip. The latter also covers a flawless power-on reset. R1 serves no function, there's a pullup inside the µC.

Comment: This really isn't anything beyond the example application in the datasheet. What are you trying to accomplish with your board?

Comment: I see the figure, I'll have some research to do on how it works.  Same goes for the reset pin.  Thanks for the input!

Comment: @whatsisname It very well may not be different.... I haven't seen that example and can't seem to find it.  Do you have a figure reference by chance?

Comment: Personally it makes me nervous to load down the SCK with a 1k and LED. I assume the purpose is so you can detect SCK activity. Apart from that, double-check all schematic symbol pinouts, and double-check that you are using the correct pins for the correct functions. That is the most common source of mistakes.

Comment: When you get to layout, double check that all PCB footprints are correct. That check needs to include verifying pin number mapping between schematic symbol and PCB footprint. It is very common to mirror image a PCB footprint, or use a SOIC with a wrong width, etc. So double-check it. If you have parts, print out the layout at 1:1 scale and set the parts on the printout to confirm sizes.

Comment: I think that an arduino board is not the kind of a good place to start if is your firt board project. You should, IMHO, start with something simpler. Besides that, there are plenty of arduino board designs in internet, so, you can research then, find the better ones and compare them to yours, instead of generically posting yours schematic in this forum as if it was a homework to be evaluated.

Comment: R3 and D1, and maybe LED2 appear to be shorted. U$ is a strange designator for a resonator.

Comment: Should out of the regulator(?) be connected to the +5V net?

Answer (score 1):

Add three 0.1uF caps from VCC and AVCC to Gnd. Install them near the pins as possible.

Add a 0.1uF cap from Aref to Gnd.

Add a diode from Reset to +5 (cathode to +5) to keep any spikes on the reset button way from reset (can make the chip think it's going into High Voltage Program mode and then look hung).

Add an FTDI header so you can connect to a PC via a USB adapter (like FTDI Basic) and download code, and debug via serial print statements. The signals needed are PD0, PDI, DTR, +5, Gnd. DTR connects to Reset thru a 0.1uF cap; DTR goes low, the cap and the 10K Reset pullup make it a pulse to kick off the bootloader (if loaded). Also helpful to have a diode between +5 from the FTDI (anode))and the output of the regulator (cathode) so the regulator can't back drive 5V into your PC if both supplies are connected - PCs often don't like that and can shut down the USB port.

If you're worried about the load on SCK for an external chip trying to drive the pin as an input, change R3 to 2.2K or 3.3K, the LED will still be plenty bright.

Comment: I also ditch the regulator in a lot of designs, and just use a 5V wallwart to power boards.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the datasheets reference circuit design is a must allways.

Also you can see how Sparkfun and Adafruit design their own circuits, to have a good reference from the schematic to the board design, they share the schematics and Eagle files. That was really usefull for me to start designing the right way.

Comment: Whilst sensible advice this would be better as a comment on the op's question, rather than an answer. It doesn't provide critique or give suggestions of what could be improved.

Comment: Thanks Collin, I will keep that in mind in my next contribution.